# Stream Closed error in twitter4j how to solve

Tags: java, credentials, twitter4j

it says Stream Closed error

```
public class StreamAPI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxx");
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxx");
        cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xx-xx");
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxx");
        cb.setUseSSL(true);
        cb.setUserStreamRepliesAllEnabled(true);


        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

        AccessToken accestoken = new AccessToken("xx-xx", "xxx");

        twitterStream.setOAuthAccessToken(accestoken);
        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }

            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
                System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
            }

            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
                System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
            }

            public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
                System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning stallWarning) {
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
        String keywords[] = {"France", "Germany"};

        fq.track(keywords);

        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        twitterStream.filter(fq);

    }

}
```

i am getting error

```
   Stream closed.
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=a8fd061d or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=00070a0c
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[a8fd061d-00070a0c a8fd061d-0007099d], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
    at twitter4j.StatusStreamBase.handleNextElement(StatusStreamBase.java:199)
    at twitter4j.StatusStreamImpl.next(StatusStreamImpl.java:57)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:478)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: the end of the stream has been reached
    at twitter4j.StatusStreamBase.handleNextElement(StatusStreamBase.java:88)
    ... 2 more
```

But the same configuration works for TwitterAPI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter gives the [following reasons why you may be disconnected](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/connecting#Disconnections):

> - A client establishes too many connections with the same credentials. When this occurs, the oldest connection will be terminated. This means
>     you have to be careful not to run two reconnecting clients in parallel
>     with the same credentials, or else they will take turns disconnecting
>     each other.
> - A client stops reading data suddenly. If the rate of Tweets being read off of the stream drops suddenly, the connection will be closed.
> - A client reads data too slowly. Every streaming connection is backed
>     by a queue of messages to be sent to the client. If this queue grows
>     too large over time, the connection will be closed.
> - A streaming server is restarted. This is usually related to a code deploy and is not very frequent.
> - Twitter's network configuration changes. These events are extremely rare, and would represent load balancer restarts or network
>     reconfigurations, for example.

You should receive information on *why* you were disconnected, [but not always](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/messages#Disconnect_messages_disconnect):

> Streams may be shut down for a variety of reasons. The streaming API will attempt to deliver a message indicating why a stream was closed. Note that if the disconnect was due to network issues or a client reading too slowly, it is possible that this message will not be received.

My thought would be that perhaps you're not reading data quickly enough - although I can't say for certain. Try implementing `onStallWarning` to see if you're getting any stall warnings, e.g.:

```
@Override
public void onStallWarning(StallWarning stallWarning) {
    System.out.println(stallWarning);
}
```